# angularjs app structure/ $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't seem to wire this up properly. I'll list the appropriate pieces. My issue is accessing the injected resources. All of the dependent pieces are undefined when I try to reference them.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource','ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid','app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  return $routeProvider.
      when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/transaction.view.html', controller: 'TransactionCtrl' }).
      when('/about', { templateUrl: 'partials/about.view.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl' }).
      when('/transaction', { templateUrl: 'partials/transaction.view.html', controller: 'TransactionCtrl' }).
      otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    return $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['logger', '$rootScope', '$q',
        function (logger, $rootScope, $q) {
            var error, success;
            success = function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("success:" + response.status, response);
                logger.log("success:" + response.status);
                return response;
            };
            error = function (response) {
                var deferred;
                deferred = $q.defer();
                $rootScope.$broadcast("error:" + response.status, response);
                logger.log("error:" + response.status);
                return $q.reject(response);
            };
            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
            };
        }
    ]);
}])
.run(['$rootScope', 'logger', function ($rootScope, logger) {
  return $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, currentRoute, priorRoute) {
      return $rootScope.$broadcast("" + currentRoute.controller + "$routeChangeSuccess", currentRoute, priorRoute);
        });
 }]);
```

...the controllers are here:

```
angular.module('pennyWatch.controllers', ['$scope', '$location','logger', 'ngGrid',     'transactionService']).
controller('TransactionCtrl', [function ($scope, logger, ngGrid, transactionService) {

//code here

}]).
controller('AboutCtrl',[function ($scope, logger) {
    $scope.logEntries = logger.logEntries;
}]);
```

So none of the resources I specified are available (all undefined): '$scope', '$location','logger', 'ngGrid', 'transactionService'

Any light shed on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: probably you are using wrong syntax it should be like controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope','logger',function ($scope, logger) {
    $scope.logEntries = logger.logEntries;
}]);

Comment: Thanks @Ajaybeniwal! I changed the controller definition to match as suggested. It appears I've taken a few steps back - now the TransactionCtrl breakpoints aren't hitting. I've put all the code in a jsfiddle (minus the views). Maybe this will help pinpoint my issues. :-)  http://jsfiddle.net/willtx/8jdLh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the syntax for a controller is:

```
.controller('TransactionCtrl', ['$scope', 'logger', 'ngGrid', 'transactionService', function ($scope, logger, ngGrid, transactionService) {

//code here

}]);
```

You first list what to inject, then as the last element of the array to define a function with parameters that will represent what's injected.

For instance you could even have:

```
.controller('TransactionCtrl', ['$scope', 'logger', 'ngGrid', 'transactionService', function ($s, logr, ngGrid, transServ) {

//code here

}]);
```

This is to allow for easy minification.

The alternative controller syntax uses the parameter names when choosing what to inject. And since minification usually involves shortening variable names, it's suggested you use the syntax above.

Alternative syntax:

```
.controller('TransactionCtrl', function ($scope, logger, ngGrid, transactionService) {

//code here

});
```

Comment: I've had more people point out my definition is incorrect but appears I have other issues as well. Thank you for your time and input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are swapping module-loading with service-injection

when declaring the `pennywatch.controllers` module, you should invoke the `angular.module` function passing the module dependencies in brackets, not the services. many of the services you cannot access are in the `ng` module, for instance

service injection is applied at the controller level